# Javascript Ajax submit multiple individual form (of same form structure) in one PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP page, where it has 12 individual form with individual form ID, and individual checkbox, dropdown etc. Like this pic:

[image]

Now, forms have Update Zone, which basically fetches, Name, Enable check or not, Time, Dim and sends it to PHP file for processing.

[Code for 3 Zones](https://pastebin.com/vwD4A7z9)

So, each form has hard coded URL LoopInfo.php?id=1 where id changes from 1 to 12, so the LoopInfo.php knows which Zone's update button is clicked and grabs post variables from that paticular zone

[PHP Processing and updating XML](https://pastebin.com/WhVjHphU)

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
        // echo "ID - ".$id.'<br>';
        if($id > 0 && $id < 13)
        {
            // ZName - 1-12
            // Zmode - 1-12
            // ZTime - 1-12
            // ZDim  - 1-12
            $radio = $_POST['radio'];
            if($radio == 1)
            {
                $radio = 0;
            }
            // echo "Radio - ".$radio.'<br>';
            $zn = "zname".$id;
            $znam = $_POST["$zn"];
            // echo "Name - ".$znam.'<br>';
            $et = "EnTim".$id;
            $entim = $_POST["$et"];
            // echo "Timer - ".$entim.'<br>';
            $ot = "OnTim".$id;
            $ontim = $_POST["$ot"];
            // echo "On Time - ".$ontim.'<br>';
            $oft = "OfTim".$id;
            $oftim = $_POST["$oft"];
            // echo "Off Time - ".$oftim.'<br>';
            $ed = "EnDim".$id;
            $endim = $_POST["$ed"];
            // echo "Dim - ".$endim.'<br>';
            $d = "Dim".$id;
            $dim = $_POST["$d"];
            // echo "Dim Per - ".$dim.'<br>';
            $bin = $radio.$endim."00000".$entim;
            // echo "Binary - ".$bin.'<br>';
            $loopval = bindec($bin);
            // echo "Loop Val - ".$loopval.'<br>';
            // print_r($_POST);
            // die;
            $hunza=simplexml_load_file('LoopInfo.xml');
            if($hunza)
            {
                $zmode='Z'.$id.'Mode';
                $hunza->$zmode=$loopval;
                if($znam == '')
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    $name='Zname'.$id;
                    $hunza->$name=$znam;
                }
                if($entim == 1)
                {
                    $ontime='Z'.$id.'TimeOn';
                    $hunza->$ontime=$ontim;
                    $oftime='Z'.$id.'TimeOff';
                    $hunza->$oftime=$oftim;
                }
                if($endim == 1)
                {
                    $dimval='Z'.$id.'Dim';
                    $hunza->$dimval=$dim;
                }
                $hunza->asXML('LoopInfo.xml');
                // echo "<script>console.log('File Updated' );</script>";
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error Loading File";
                echo "<script>console.log('Error Load File' );</script>";
            }
        }
```

So basically, each one is a form, when pressed on Update zone, grabs all form data, gives it to LoopInfo.php and LoopInfo.php updates those values to XML in their corresponding tags.

Target: What I am trying to achieve is that, is there any way, where I can update zone without the page being reloaded i.e., using Ajax Javascript. So Javascript grabs all value on update from form, creates Ajax request and post to the same PHP file for processing. I tried Googling "Javascript Ajax Multiple Form send data in one PHP" with no results. Is it possible to get a generic function which when invokes get the form Id and get to know this is ID 1 and created URL LoopInfo.php?id=1 and sends all form data along with this URL request.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is cause of event propagation. Check your event - is it cause of multiple times form is submitting. 
To avoid this place `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`